# I am small but very precious

Tags: riddle

> I am small but very precious.
>  If you cut off my head, I will live in
>   the UK.
>  If you cut off my tail, I will be a fruit.
>  And if you cut off my
>   head and my tail, I will be part of your body.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are a:

> **Pearl**

If you cut my head, I will live in UK.

> **Earls** are British nobility

If you cut my tail, I will be a fruit.

> **Pear** is a fruit

And if you cut my head and my tail, I will be part of your body.

> The **ear** is a part of our body

Comment: Bravo. You answer it very fast.

Comment: Thank you. FWIW, I got the fruit first by recognizing the body part in it, and that got me the actual answer.